# R will not run on mac os high sierra after installing with homebrew dyld: Library not loaded error

Tags: r, homebrew

Following this post I used the following steps:

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install Caskroom/cask/xquartz
brew install r
```

Then when trying to run R, I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.3_1/lib/libR.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by uninstalling and reinstalling readline:

```
brew uninstall readline
brew install readline
```